# cx_Freeze flashes a cmd window even using Win32GUI

Tags: python, pyside, cx-freeze, python-multiprocessing

I am new to cx_Freeze. 
I started using it in a big python application. That application is using PySide and uses multiprocessing. On application start and each time a thread starts I see a cmd window flashing shortly (just open and close really quick.. no time to read anything).
Now I tried with a very simple application. Like this:

```
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing

from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtNetwork   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # multiprocessing support
    multiprocessing.freeze_support() 

    # init application
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    # check systemtray    
    if not QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable():
        QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Systray", "I couldn't detect any system tray on this system.")
        sys.exit(1)  # quick kill
    wid = QtGui.QWidget()
    wid.resize(250, 150)
    wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    wid.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But this is still showing and flashing a window on start.
Here is the setup file I use with this:

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
# dependencies
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": [#"os", "sys", "glob", "re", "atexit", 
                 "PySide.QtCore", "PySide.QtGui", "PySide.QtXml", 'PySide.QtXml', 
                 'xml', 'P4', 'MYRefs_module', 'MYUtils_module', 'logging',
                 'multiprocessing'],
    # "include_files": mfiles, # this isn't necessary after all
    "excludes": ["Tkinter", "Tkconstants", "tcl"],
    "build_exe": "build",
    "icon": "img/icon.ico",
    "include_msvcr":True
}

executable = [
    Executable("main.pyw",
               base="Win32GUI",
               initScript = None,
               targetName="Example.exe",
               targetDir="build",
               copyDependentFiles=True,
               )
]

setup(
    name="Example",
    version="0.1",
    description="Example", # Using the word "test" makes the exe to invoke the UAC in win7. WTH?
    author="Me",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executable,
    requires=['PySide', 'cx_Freeze', 'P4', 'xml']
)
```

May be I am doing something wrong? Is the multiprocessing support the issue? Any hint appreciated.
Btw, I am using python 2.7.3x64 and cx_Freeze 4.3.4, PySide 1.2.2 ...

Answer (score 1):

solved.
And after finding the problem, the question was probably not right.
I catch a os.system('rd /s /q somefolder') call. In one of my modules loaded.
As soon as I remove that, which is not necessary right now, the console window flashes dont show again. 
I used it in one single place, but the flashes appeared in several places (threads). I used as well Popen, which apparently works fine.

Comment: If you do need to delete a directory from Python, there's [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree).